# what does "executable" property defined in plugin configuration mean?

Tags: maven

I come across a `POM.xml`, confused by the following part of it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
        <additionalClasspathElements>${basedir}/target/conf,${basedir}/../conf</additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

what the above `executable` do? is it okay for me to remove the line?

Comment: Although there isn't much in the Docs for this plugins My guess is that goal and executable are pre-configured (available) setups within the plugin code. Not sure though. My suggestion is, remove it and test and see what happens.

Comment: @JorgeCampos nothing fancy happened after I removed the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simply answer to this is cause `executable` is not a valid configuration for the goal `java`...See the [docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html).

Only for the goal [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal there is a parameter `executable`...